# How many triangles in the picture?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Sorry if this has already been asked before. Is there any formula for such questions?

[image: How many triangles in the picture?]

EDIT:

I have numbered the smallest triangles in the picture and marked the pentagon as x.
Then I listed all the possibilities. Could you please check if I have missed anything?

[image]

1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
23,
34,
45,
56,
67,
78,
345,
567,
2x8,
2x6,
234x8,
2x876,
1x465,
1x4,
1x6,
8x4

Comment: Formula maybe not, but there definitely is an algorithm. Just start in one point, then form all triangles you can with that point as a corner, count them. Then remove that point from the diagram and choose a new point. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Start with a graph $\Omega$. Pick a node $A$ and remove the nodes not connected to $A$. Pick a second node $B$. Count how many nodes are connected to $B$ that are outside of line $AB$. Remove $B$ and repeat until there's only $A$ left. Go back to $\Omega$, remove $A$ and repeat the whole process (cumulatively removing the $A$'s from $\Omega$) until all nodes are gone. Not very practical to do by hand, but I got $24$ as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from [Raskolnikov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3567/raskolnikov) and [Wood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/196858/wood) the answer is **24** triangles.

Answer (score 1):

No formula. I simply counted them and got 22.

There are 9 individual parts, out of which 8 are triangles themselves.

- Triangles made by 1 part - 8
- Made by 2 parts - 5
- Made by 3 parts - 6
- Made by 4 parts - 0
- Made by 5 parts - 3

Total 22.

Comment: Sorry but I'm already getting 24 triangles. But I guess the actual answer is even more than 24. Could you please help?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, didn't count 8x4 and 2x6. 
But yes, there is no formula, and not many ways to check this answer. 

But there might be a formula for calculating the maximum number of triangles that can be made with a given number of line segments.